# Matrix exponential, containing a thermal state

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential, infinite-matrices

Define an infinite matrix $$ M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 2 & 0 & -3 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Numerically, I've found that the first column of $\exp(M)$ is given by $\alpha(1,e^{-\lambda},e^{-2\lambda},e^{-3\lambda},\dots)^T$, where $\lambda \approx 0.27$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{1-e^{-2\lambda}} \approx 0.65$.

> **Question:** How to prove analytically that the first column of $\exp(M)$ has the stated form?

[Context: This question comes from a quantum mechanical model of two harmonic oscillators coupled by a Hamiltonian of the form $\hat{H} \propto \hat{a}_1^\dagger \hat{a}_2^\dagger - \hat{a}_1 \hat{a}_2$, where $\hat{a}_i$ is the lowering operator for oscillator $i$.  The matrix $M$ is precisely this Hamiltonian on the subspace spanned by $\{\left|nn\right>\}$.  I've tried using a [BCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) approach, but was discouraged by the fact that the commutators are not very cooperative.  The exponential coefficients in the first column indicates (roughly) a thermal state.]

---

**Edit:** I [cross-posted this on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293637/matrix-exponential-containing-a-thermal-state), and got a beautiful solution by Jochen Glueck.  The exact value of $\lambda$ is $-\ln(\tanh(1))$.

Comment: Trying this numerical for the $3 \times 3$ version, I do **not** get the same result

Comment: That being said, it might be helpful to consider the first column of $\exp(Mt)$ (function of $t$ for $t \geq 0$) as the unique solution to the linear differential equation
$$
\frac {d \mathbf x}{dt} = M \mathbf x, \qquad \mathbf x(0) = (1,0,\dots,0)^T
$$

Comment: [(see the $3 \times 3$ computation on WA here)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp%5B%7B%7B0,-1,0%7D,%7B1,0,-2%7D,%7B0,2,0%7D%7D%5D+*+%7B%7B1%7D,%7B0%7D,%7B0%7D%7D)

Comment: Oh, I missed that this was an infinite matrix earlier... sorry

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I added the word "infinite" in the description to hopefully avert further confusion.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom For the numerical stuff, I of course had to truncate the matrix.  Roughly the first half of the first column for a truncated matrix has the stated form.  So if you want to see this behavior for 10 elements, you should truncate to at least a 20 by 20 matrix.

Comment: I tried to find the spectrum of $H$ since **if** it was discrete (with analytic eigenvectors) one could write $H=U^\dagger DU$ with $U$ unitary, $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$ containing the eigenvalues of $H$. That would mean $\exp(H)=U^\dagger\operatorname{diag}(\exp(\lambda_1),\exp(\lambda_2),\ldots)U$. Sadly the spectrum of $H$ does not behave as nicely as the usual Hamiltonian of the harm. oscillator $H'=\operatorname{diag}(\frac12,\frac32,\ldots)$ as so far I only could show that $\sigma_p(H)\subseteq(-1,1)$ so I don't think my approach will be of too much use here.

Comment: @Yly Good to know

Comment: Cross posting this on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293637/matrix-exponential-containing-a-thermal-state